# Please guide me books and online materials for this course

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, book-recommendation, online-resources

I have recently taken Course on Numerical Analysis. It is correspondence course. So i to do self study. I will be glad if someone mentions online videos and elementary books which contains following topics:

> Approximate   numbers.   Significant   figures.   Ab solute,   relative   and  percentage error. General formula to estimate the error in a function.
>
> Descarte's rule of sings. Location of roots. Bisection, Secant, Regular Falsi, Newton-Raphson Methods, Order of convergence of these methods.
>
> Direct Methods-Gauss Elimination, Gauss-Jordan, LU decomposition, Cholesky Decomposition, Iterative Methods-Jacobi, Gauss-Seidel.
>
> Eigen values-Jacobi Method, Givens' Method, Householder's Method, Power Method, QR Method.
>
> Interpolation - Finite differences, Forward, Backward and central differences, Symbolic Relations, Detection of error using difference table. Divided differences and their properties. Interpolation formulas - Newton's, Gauss', Stirling and Bessel's, Lagrange's.
>
> Numerical differentiation using interpolation formulas.
>
> Numerical integration. General formula. Trapezoidal, Simpson on-third and three-eights formulae. newton-Cote's Formulae.
>
> Euler Method. Euler modified. Picard methods. Runge Kutta second and fourth order methods, Milne-Thompson method.

Comment: I can recommend “Introduction to Numerical Analysis” from Stoer and Bulirsch.

Comment: @Wauzl Is it suitable for self study for first course

Comment: You can have a look inside on the amazon page, for example. Tastes are different and I do not know your background. I have to admit, though, that is not exactly easy reading.